# Passage in Progressive Tense

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I extracted this passage from 1984 because I am looking for passages written in *Past Progressive Tense* or *Present Progressive Tense*.  I would think it is written in Present Progressive Tense but I'm not quite sure.

> In its second minute the Hate rose to a frenzy. People were leaping up
> and down  in their places and shouting at the tops of their voices in
> an effort to drown the  maddening bleating voice that came from the
> screen. The little sandy-haired woman had  turned bright pink, and her
> mouth was opening and shutting like that of a landed fish.  Even
> O’Brien’s heavy face was flushed. He was sitting very straight in his
> chair, his  powerful chest swelling and quivering as though he were
> standing up to the assault of a  wave. The dark-haired girl behind
> Winston had begun crying out ‘Swine! Swine! Swine!’  and suddenly she
> picked up a heavy Newspeak dictionary and flung it at the screen. It
> struck Goldstein’s nose and bounced off; the voice continued
> inexorably. In a lucid  moment Winston found that he was shouting with
> the others and kicking his heel   violently against the rung of his
> chair.

Comment: Is this passage talking about the past or the present? Let's see in "…the Hate rose to a frenzy" Is the main verb in the simple present or simple past? Is the auxiliary "**were** leaping" in the present or the past?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe we should delete this question as there is not one example of is/am/are + present participle which is the present progressive tense. No research to show the tenses.

Comment: While our Meta site does have the *resource-request* tag (which I've added), I don't think requests this vague and with this little effort belong here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is vague and shows little effort.

Comment: The question is simple but you have no intention of answering it.  I thought whether the passage is in Present Progressive Tense.  Either Yes or No.

Comment: If you're asking whether the specific quoted passage is in Present Progressive Tense, then wouldn't this question belong on the main ELL site, not Meta?

Comment: That is my frustration.  Firstly, somebody started migrating my questions here.  Then I get complaints here.  Seems like a setup to me.

Comment: @Bhimas - hostile and angry comments are a sure way of getting down- and close-votes, and of **not** getting the help you want.

Comment: If somebody migrated here your questions, that is eventually their fault. The meta site is for asking questions about how the main site works, the questions that can be asked on the main site (including the tags to use for those questions), or the answers that can be given to those questions.

Answer (score 3):

> That is my frustration. Firstly, somebody started migrating my questions here. Then I get complaints here. Seems like a setup to me

I don't know why a question of yours was migrated to meta in the first place, but since then you've posted several English language questions on **ELL Meta**, this is the wrong place. Please go on the main page. There is no conspiracy against you, and the "complaints" are comments explaining how to fix things.

I've looked at your accounts on several Stack Exchange websites and this is the first (?) time you have posted anything on meta. If you visit Stack Overflow, [Emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) etc. you'll see that each site has its own meta this is the place where users can ask questions specifically about the site, e.g. how reputation works, why a question was closed, what is plagiarism, what is on topic and off-topic etc.

Four of your meta questions were deleted recently (only visible to users with 10k+ reputation):

1. [Relationship of Tenses with Verbs](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5950/)
2. [Classify Simple, Perfect, Non-Perfect, Non-Progressive, and Progressive development of a story](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5949/)
3. [Perfect and Simple Tense](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5947/)
4. [Past Simple distinct from Past Perfect](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/)

They're off-topic here and, with the exception of question 4, they show no research or effort whatsoever. That probably explains why they were not migrated to the main site but the mod responsible should have explained this to you.